# Software to track incoming calls & manage voice messages for our business?

Tags: open-source, web-apps

I am looking for a Software App which can monitor all our incoming calls and record our calls with customers ( We will notify the customer that we will record the call for quality purpose ) and store the transcript of the conversation ..